# Overriding authorization rules in machine.config

Tags: iis, web-config, authorization, iis-express, machine.config

I have the following code which works fine in web.config, but doesn't work when used in machine.config:

```
<authorization> 
    <allow roles="admins"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

I'm using IIS Express that comes with Visual Studio 2015.
The code is placed under  *configuration / system.web*.

I've checked that I'm using a correct machine.config file by adding invalid configuration and forcing the app to crash.

The reason why I want to do this in machine.config is because we have a test server with lots of applications on it. All applications should be password protected / not accessible by search engines, unauthorized users, etc.

Sometimes developers forget to set up web.config correctly, and we would like to prevent this by overriding authorization rules on the server level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the machine.config folder you can find a web.config file. Put the settings there.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to set authorization rules for the specific path, like in the "regular" web.config? I want to deny access to all unauthorized users, but location path="my-path" should be accessible to everyone. This doesn't seem to work in web.config file that is located in the same folder as machine.config. Thanks!

Comment: @šljaker you can try to put the location tag in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config